# Sending keystrokes to an application with a file as the source

Tags: vmware, file-transfer, remote, copy-paste, keystrokes

I've had numerous times that I've needed to transfer a batch file or other text to a remote computer (not on the same network) that doesn't support copy/paste or have a "chat"/file transfer feature (either via remote access program or more frequently, VMWare vSphere console sessions - we don't allow the flag to allow copy/paste to the VMs).  I know are things such as SendKeys where you can basically write a batch file to send things, but I need something a bit more flexible.  Carriage returns need to be handled as well, so I can't just pipe the file to SendKeys either.

I'm also not wanting to use more public paste sites as I would like to be able to not have the text out on the Internet for whomever to see from now until who knows when.  Doing it this way, or sharing a file out to be downloaded, also tends to take a bit of work to setup and then you have to type the URL on the other end too...

How can this be done?

Comment: if you can ssh, try scp

Comment: No, can't do direct connections to these computers from mine (and they are usually Windows computers).

Comment: check this, last two answers http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/82233-read-a-file-and-send-line-per-line/.